# How can I change Windows 7 Embedded desktop background?

Tags: desktop-customization, windows-embedded-7

I have just taken delivery of an HP t510 Thin Client, which I am currently configuring.

However, for the default auto-logon user account, I cannot figure out how to change the desktop background.

I have logged in as the Administrator and disabled EWF, allowing me to install software and change the Administrator profile. However, logging in to the auto-logon account still does not allow me to change the desktop background (rigth clicking brings up no context menu, and the option is not available via the control panel).

How can I achieve this?

## Update

As suggested in one of the andsers, I have added the auto-login account to the `Administrators` group. While the account successfully added, it still will not allow me to access most Control Panel features.

I manaually tried accessing the Control Panel by first entering the available `Display` options and then changing the address to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\`. This resulted in the following error -

> Accessing the resource 'Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\' has been dissallowed.

I looked in to this error and two posibilites were that either of the following GPO keys were enabled, but they were not -

- User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove Run menu from Start Menu
- User Configuration\AdministrativeTemplates\Start Menu & Taskbar\Disable Control Panel

Wondering if it was something somewhere in the GPO that is causing the issue, I tried running `gpresult`, but I'm unable to even enter `Cmd`, so I can't check that.

Next I tried to change the desktop background via `regedit`, but the SID for the account in question (User) is not available -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean this auto-login account is limited, and for that reason you have no access. The best way is to temporarily add this user account to the Administrators group, then login with this user, make the changes, log out and back into the administrator account to remove the user from the Administrators group.

Comment: Ah, good plan. I'll try that when I'm back in the office tomorrow...

Comment: I have successfully added the auto-login account to the `Administrators` group, but I'm still unable to access much of the Control Panel. Manually entering a CP page (such as `appwiz.cpl` results in a window flashing up on the screen and then immediatly disapearing.

Comment: That sounds like a group policy being affected. Try logging in with a different user and see if you can start the group policy editor.

Comment: The PC is an out of the box HP t510 WES7 machine, so AV wise there is nothing on there, and there are no GPO's (externally) being applied. As mentiond about though, it's not letting me check `gpresult`! Also the admin account is fine, so I think it's specific security software embedded by HP doing this.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. You're using the build-in Administrator account on windows 7. This is a bad idea. The account is disabled on purpose and has very little rights on purpose. You should create a new account and set things up like that. I'm sure that'll work. Administrator has been disabled due to the abuse in XP where users were by default "Administrator". Spyware will try and login with that user.